# Null set-Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

How to prove that if $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is null set, then for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a countable collection of open intervals $(A_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $A \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \ell(A_{n}) < \varepsilon$.

Comment: That's one possible **definition**. If you don't tell us your definition, we can't help you.

Comment: What would happen if this were not the case? Try proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

The out measure is defined by the infimum of the sums of open coverings. If this infimum is 0, for each $\epsilon>0$, must exist a covering by open sets such that the sum is $<\epsilon$. (If not, the infimum will be $>\epsilon $, an absurd